# Differentiating between MinValue of double and Minimum of NumericUpDown

Tags: c#, double

On Value changed event of a `Telerik NumricUpDown` control ( I am thinkingit should be very similar to .NET's nuilt it updown control) I want one thing: If user clears out the value in the updown control and goes to another control on the page, set the value back to minimum of accepted value for the updown control.

So I have a logic like this:

```
void MyNumericUpDown_ValueChanged(object sender, RadRangeBaseValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (this.Value == null) // if value is cleared by user.
        {

            this.Value = this.Minimum;
        }
    }
```

This should work when in XAML I have explicitly set Minimum property for the control **but** when I haven't set it in XAML, it is using .NET's double.MinValue which is a crazy number and sets it in the control.

How Can I update the logic to know if it is not set by me in XAML,set it to **"Zero"** and not to that .NET's min value.

Comment: Some bugs are hard to find.  Not this one.  You'd be better off to *not* try to work around it since it will hide a bug.  Otherwise simple: this.Value = (this.Minimum == double.MinValue) ? 0 : this.Minimum;

Comment: Thanks, How about adding a Math.Round around double comparisons? Is it safer?

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly the way you dig yourself a giant hole.  Maybe you can reason about rounding a value with 308 digits before the decimal point, I don't have enough fingers to make sense of it.  Which matches your computer's problem, it doesn't either.

Comment: Yeah, I would just ensure that the Minimum property is set in XAML and avoid the problem altogether.  Is there ever a case when you cannot guarantee that the value is set in XAML?  It would seem that if it is something you manually do, then you could make sure that it is always set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
if (this.Value == null) // if value is cleared by user.
{
    this.Value = (this.Minimum == double.MinValue) ? 0 : this.Minimum;
}
```

Comment: if this.Value == null, it just means users hasn't typed anything in it or has cleared what was in the control...Which makes two cases: Does the XAML have defined an explicit Minimum ? If yes? Use that..In no then set it to zero..Your logic doesn't do that.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't fully interpret the question.  Hans Passant gave a viable answer in his comment.  I'll update my answer with his suggestion.

Comment: Thanks, How about adding a Math.Round around double comparisons? Is it safer?